# C# Razor - Display value from list based on key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to display some text from a list depending on the key:

```
<td>@x.OutcomeSummary</td>
<td>@Model.SummaryOutcomes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == x.OutcomeSummary).Name</td>
<td>@Model.SummaryOutcomes.FirstOrDefault(x.OutcomeSummary).Name</td>
```

In this case `x.OutcomeSummary` is 7 and I would like for it to get the relevant text from SummaryOutcomes with a key of 7.

The second line gives me the following error: *System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

And the third line gives me an error saying that the FirstOrDefault command has invalid arguments.

It imports the following model:

```
public class DogSummaryView
{
    public IEnumerable<DogIncident> Incidents { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> SummaryOutcomes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> DogBreeds { get; set; }
}
```

This is the category class:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool InUse { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Summary()
{
    var vm = new DogSummaryView
    {
        Incidents = repository.GetAllRecords().OrderByDescending(x => x.DateRecieved),
        SummaryOutcomes = repository.GetAllSummaryOutcomes()
    };

    return View("Summary", vm);
}
```

And finally here you can see that the list is populated and initialized:

[image]

Is there anyway of getting it so that instead of displaying 7, it displays the correct summary outcome?

Thanks

---

Thank you so so much to fourpastmidnight for his persistent help with this, and not only helping me to find a solution, but also helping me to understand just exactly where the problem lied. Here's an updated (working!) solution:

```
@foreach (var x in Model.Incidents)
{
    var summaryOutput = "";
    var firstOutcomeSummary = Model.SummaryOutcomes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == x.OutcomeSummary);
    if (firstOutcomeSummary != null) { summaryOutput = Model.SummaryOutcomes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == x.OutcomeSummary).Name.ToString(); }

     <tr>
        <td>@Html.Raw(summaryOutput)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize SummaryOutcomes?

Comment: can you post your controller

Comment: Agree with @user1714556, is it initialized? Furthermore, the argument to `FirstOrDefault` on line 3 is incorrect. It should read: `@Model.SummaryOutcomes.FirstOrDegault(c => c.Value == x.OutcomeSummary).Name`. -- And , I just noticed that after suggesting that, the 3rd line now matches the second.... So check that `SummaryOutcomes` is initialized. In your controller action method, you should add the `SummaryOutcomes` collection to the view model returned to the view.

Comment: Thank you, I believe it is initialized in the controller (I have updated the question with the controller). Also please pardon my ignorance by why is it c. rather than y.? (I've updated that too!) - thanks again

Comment: @Nick see @Rui answer below. It's the most likely cause. As for `c` vs. `y`, it doesn't matter. That's just a lambda variable for the anonymous function. I prefer to use lambda variables that are 1 character and that match the first character of the type the lambda is operating over. Since `SummaryOutcomes` is an `IEnumerable<Category>`, I chose `c` for `Category`.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for the explanation, that does make sense to use c in this case.

Comment: To display the enum constant name, use `Enum.GetName(Type t, object value)` method; e.g. `Enum.Getname(typeof(SummaryOutcome), SummaryOutcome.WhateverThisValueIs)`.

Comment: @Nick: I would refactor your code for the `if` statement as follows: `if (firstOutcomeSummary != null) { /*(new line here)*/ <tr><td>@firstOutcomeSummary.Name</td></tr> /*(new line here)*/ }. Since `firstOutcomeSummary` is not null, you can directly access the `Name` property. Also, I would not use `@Html.Raw()`--this could lead to script injection attacks, unless you're carefully sanitizing user input; even so, I still wouldn't do it unless absolutely necessary. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem is you're trying to compare a `string` to an `int`.

Change the second line as follows:

```
@Model.SummaryOutcomes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == x.OutcomeSummary.ToString()).Name;

// You could also use '.Value'.
```

That should solve your problem.

**UPDATE**

Hmm, maybe `x.OutcomeSummary.ToString()` is resulting in the type name of the enumeration and not the integer value of the enumeration constant value.

Try updating the above line to the following:

```
@Model.SummaryOutcomes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == ((int)x.OutcomeSummary).ToString()).Name;
```

**UPDATE 2014-03-21**

According to the OP's latest comment, try the following:

```
// If x.OutcomeSummary is the outcome summary name, then....
var firstOutcomeSummary = @Model.SummaryOutcomes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == x.OutcomeSummary)
if (firstOutcomeSummary != null)
    // Do something here.

// Else, if x.OutcomeSummary is the outcome summary value, e.g. "7", then...
var firstOutcomeSummary = @Model.SummaryOutcomes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == x.OutcomeSummary)
if (firstOutcomeSummary != null)
    // Do something here.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for each line now though it just displays dangerousdogsdatabase.models.Category instead of the value. I've tried adding .Name and .Value at the end too with no joy :(

Comment: Hmm, I updated my answer to append `.Name` to the line of code above; but you already mentioned this didn't seem to work. I'm at a loss as to why this wouldn't work off the top of my hed.

Comment: Thank you, with both I get the same error as before: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Nick updated my answer -- maybe I should have wrapped `x.OutcomeSummary` in parenthesis before calling `ToString()` on it.

Comment: Thank you again for the help, unfortunately I get an "Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'" error and when I remove the (int) from before x.OutcomeSummary I get the regular "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error :(

Comment: @Nick: Ah, then there's your problem!! The `x.OutcomeSummary` is not an `int`, it's a `string`. That's not what I was lead to believe from your code snippets. Check exactly what `x.OutcomeSummary` is in the debugger--then all you need to do is match up that value with the correct value on the Category being checked for in the lambda anonymous method in the `FirstOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate)` call.

Comment: Oh! Thank you, you're right - it is a string! Pardon my stupidity though but I believe it is matched up correctly how it was originally? Though I've never actually used Lamba queries before so I'm probably way off on this.

Comment: By the way, for some reason even though x.OutcomeSummary is a string, the value is only 7... so it is the key for the list

Comment: @Nick: Then in my updated answer for today, you should use the second part of the example where I compare the `Category` value (`c.Value`) to `x.OutcomeSummary`. You should get something back. Also, **be sure to get rid of your third `<td>` in your OP code since its syntax is incorrect and will give you an error.**

Comment: Thank you so so so so much for your continued help! It works! I have posted the full solution in the original question :) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

*FirstOrDefault* will do just that return the *first* element that matches the predicate or return default, i.e. *null*. Calling *.Name* on a *null* object will throw a *NullReferenceException*

In sum, the behavior you are describing will occur if there's no instance of *Category* in the enumeration *SummaryOutcomes* whose value is 7.

Comment: +1 Good call. Let's not forget the obvious (besides forgetting to initialize the value in the model). :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, there definitely is an OutcomeSummary with a value of 7 though, so I think I've messed up somewhere else

Comment: @Nick perhaps you're matching the `x.OutcomeSummary` value against the wrong property on `Category`; e.g. `Category.Value` is not an `OutcomeSummary`? Maybe add a quick snippet showing the shape of the `Category` class to your OP.